# Secure script for user authentication

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using [UserPie](https://github.com/booruguru/UserPie), is the connection with mysqli, but I do not know if the script if it is safe or not?

I'm no expert, so I ask you how to make it "updated" with the functions `mysqli`?

It's useless to paste the files of interest here - you can see everything you need from GitHub, as I said, I set up a connection with `mysqli`, is not already enough (most obviously encrypted passwords).

Comment: You could log a ticket and see if the author will help - it's rather too broad a question for Stack Overflow. I personally wouldn't use this repo - there are a lot of practices that need improvement. It looks like the author is aware of SQL injection, which is a good thing, but sanatisation using devices like `strtolower(strip_tags(trim(($str))))` shows there are probably a lot of things to fix. Are there no scripts that do things right first time?

Comment: I contacted the author, but has no answer yet. Unfortunately, not being an expert I was fine with this to build my own script. I wanted to try IonAuth, which I understand is a lot better, but I had a bit of trouble.

Comment: I've not looked at the code, but http://usercake.com/ seems to be popular.

Comment: Could you take a quick look at the file? The connection is via mysqli, only that they are insecure about the functions, are dated and insecure against SQL ignition?

Comment: Which file do you mean? What functions are insecure, and what is SQL Ignition?

Comment: I mean SQL injection, however, all the script in general is safe? I can use it without any problems? his "classes" are old?

Comment: Do you mean Usercake? I've no idea, I'm afraid. I just tried to find a public repo for their project, and could not find one on their site - so on second thoughts, use something else (if they don't have a public repo, it may not be any good). Perhaps search GitHub instead.